# Unable to access Bower in Laravel app directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, bower

I have recently started using Bower (or trying to!) to manage the packages within my Laravel 4 application. The two main ones being Bootstrap and jQuery.

My footer, using Blade is:

```
{{HTML::script('bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}
{{HTML::script('packages/bootstrap/css/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}
```

The link it displays is `http://localhost:8888/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js`, which is correct.

The 'packages' folder is accessible, but it can't find a thing inside the bower_components directory. I have set the permissions to -R 755 on the bower_components directory but it still isn't accessible.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like it is not downloading those packages.

I don't like this `bower_components` folder it defaults to. This is how I'm using it:

I have a `.bowerrc` file which tells bower where the assets should lie:

```
{
    "directory": "public/assets/vendor"
}
```

I ran

```
bower init
```

And every time I bower install something:

```
bower install jquery -S
```

It downloads, installs and adds them in the bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "MySite",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    "font-awesome": "~4.0.3",
    "datatables": "~1.9.4"    
  }
}
```

I make sure files were downloaded and installed:

```
ls -la public/assets/vendor
```

Then I just have to create my routes using:

```
{{ HTML::style('assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}

{{ HTML::style('assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}

{{ HTML::script('assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}
```

I don't really mind much about permissions, because files must just be readable by web server and they usually are.

Comment: Ah, I've just figured it out (my solution below). Exactly the same just I'm using the public directory! Thank you though, Antonio!

Answer (score 6):

I created a .bowerrc folder within the root directory and added the following code:

```
{
  "directory": "public/bower_components"
}
```

I then created a bower.json using the `bower init` command.

Then I installed both packages, jQuery and Bootstrap and referenced them as such:

```
{{HTML::script('bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}
{{HTML::script('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}
```